# android studio のエミュレータが遅すぎる

Tags: android-studio

android studio のエミュレータが遅すぎるのですが、初期だとこんなものなんでしょうか？

**環境**
CPU:Core i7-6500U 2.5GHz
メモリ:8GB
HDD:1TB
ODD:Blu-ray
OS:Windows10 Home 64bit
Office:Polaris Office

Comment: 使用しているハードウェア・OS・メモリ・DISK・ソフトウェア等の種類・量・性能・版数とか、どこからどこまでを計って、その時間がどのくらいとかの、そうした性能などに影響するであろう具体的な情報や数値が無いようなので追記してください。

Comment: ちなみにこんな記事があるようですが。[Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 & Win10 システム要件 スペック メモ](https://neet-rookie.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/20/144234), [【2021年最新版】Android Studio インストール手順（Windows）](https://senoriblog.com/androidstudio-install/), [プログラミングに適したノートPCのCPU・メモリについて](https://teratail.com/questions/213392)

Comment: 私のPCでもめちゃ遅いですね。特に起動するまでが、なので開発中は極力閉じないようにしています。

Comment: ちなみにx86エミュレータは入っていますよね。通常のエミュレータよりx86エミュレータのほうが早いです。